# fast conversion from edge list to adjacency matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, network-programming

What is the most efficient approach to convert an edge list into an adjacency matrix in Python?
Below is my best shot so far, but still very slow for what I need.

```py
import string
import random
import pandas as pd

users = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(100)]
connections = 100000

edge_list = pd.DataFrame({'source':[random.choice(users) for _ in range(connections)],
              'target':[random.choice(users) for _ in range(connections)],
              'event':[random.choice(['event1', 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', 'event5']) for _ in range(connections)]})

adj_matrix = edge_list.groupby(['source', 'target'])['target'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

```py
%%timeit
adj_matrix = edge_list.groupby(['source', 'target'])['target'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

`9.95 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: Polars might be another good option, 2x faster in my test:
df.group_by("source", "target").count().pivot(values="count", index="source", columns="target", aggregate_function="sum")

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `pd.factorize` your `source`/`target` columns and construct the adjacency matrix with `numpy`:

```py
def get_adj_matrix(edge_list):
    source_codes, source_uniques = pd.factorize(edge_list["source"])
    target_codes, target_uniques = pd.factorize(edge_list["target"])

    out = np.zeros((len(source_uniques), len(target_uniques)), dtype=np.int32)
    np.add.at(out, (source_codes, target_codes), 1)

    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=source_uniques, columns=target_uniques, copy=False)
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
import random
import string

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import perfplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def get_edge_list(connections):
    users = [
        "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(10))
        for _ in range(100)
    ]

    edge_list = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "source": [random.choice(users) for _ in range(connections)],
            "target": [random.choice(users) for _ in range(connections)],
            "event": [
                random.choice(["event1", "event2", "event3", "event4", "event5"])
                for _ in range(connections)
            ],
        }
    )

    return edge_list


def get_adj_matrix(edge_list):
    source_codes, source_uniques = pd.factorize(edge_list["source"])
    target_codes, target_uniques = pd.factorize(edge_list["target"])

    out = np.zeros((len(source_uniques), len(target_uniques)), dtype=np.int32)
    np.add.at(out, (source_codes, target_codes), 1)

    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=source_uniques, columns=target_uniques, copy=False)

plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

perfplot.show(
    setup=get_edge_list,
    kernels=[
        lambda edge_list: edge_list.groupby(["source", "target"])["target"]
        .count()
        .unstack(fill_value=0),
        lambda edge_list: pd.crosstab(edge_list["source"], edge_list["target"]),
        get_adj_matrix,
    ],
    labels=["groupby", "crosstab", "pd.factorize"],
    n_range=[10, 100, 1000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 50000, 100000, 200000],
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=None,
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems above 10^5 groupby is slightly faster or equal.

Comment: @FranciscoZanartu The speed depends on character of your real data (how many unique groups you have etc.) - so test it on the real thing.